# Using Java to Command Matlab

Tags: java, matlab

I'm trying to use use Matlab to:

1. Create a new Java process to spawn a 2nd instance of Matlab and then
2. Write a command to that 2nd instance of Matlab from the first instance of Matlab.

The code seems to run fine, but I don't see anything appear in the command window of the 2nd Matlab instance. What am I doing wrong?

The code I've tried is:

```
% Start a 2nd instance of Matlab
MatlabProcess = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec('matlab -nosplash');
pause(20); % I don't know if this pause is really needed.

% Set up a buffered Java stream writer to write to the new Matlab Process
OutputStream            = MatlabProcess.getOutputStream();
OutputStreamWriter      = java.io.OutputStreamWriter(OutputStream);
OutputBufferedWriter    = java.io.BufferedWriter(OutputStreamWriter);

% Write some text to the 2nd Matlab Instance
OutputBufferedWriter.write('pi\n');
OutputBufferedWriter.flush();
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you get either a command window, or use of stdin/stdout, not both, depending on whether the matlab process is interactive.

Comment: When I start the seconds Matlab instance with:
MatlabProcess = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec('matlab -nosplash -nodesktop');
then the command window is not started and I can read output from the spawned instance of Matlab through getInputStream().
I still cant write to the output stream with the above code though.  The code seems to execute OK, but nothing appears to be written to the 2nd instance of Matlab.

Comment: @Greg: You don't write to the output stream, you write to the input stream (which means child process's stdin).  Wait, no, the Java documentation is all screwed up.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm fairly new to Java and am confused by the idea of writing to an InputStream.
As far as I understand, Java InputStreams don't have a write() method.  Java OutputStreams do however:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html
I must be missing something but am having a difficult time understanding what it is.

Comment: @Greg: Usually when you start a child process, you get a handle to its `stdin`, which you write to and the child process reads.  And vice versa for the child processes `stdout`.  And [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) use that terminology here: "failure to promptly **write the input stream or read the output stream** of the subprocess may cause the subprocess to block".  But later "Gets the input stream of the subprocess. The stream obtains data piped from the standard output stream of the process represented by this Process object".  It's a mess.

Comment: The "right" thing would be to have a method `getStdin()` which returns an `OutputStream`, and `getStdout()` would return an `InputStream`, and there would be no confusion.

Comment: @Greg: In summary though, I think you're doing it right, and the Java `Process` methods were named and documented by a bunch of idiots.

Comment: Thanks.  The strange part about this is that I can call readLine() on an InputStreamReader object and successfully read text lines from the Command Window of child Matlab process (when invoked with the -nodesktop switch) . On the other hand when I call write('pi\n') on the OutputStreamWriter for this same process, it doesn't appear to do anything.

Comment: @Greg: You want also try `"\r\n"`.  Wait is this Java code in Java, or Java objects used from MatLab.  Java uses double-quotes for strings, a single quote would be just a single character.