# how can we save result of Command window on file, MATLAB

Tags: java, matlab

In fact what i want to do is recuperate the result of command window on Matlab in a file .mat (How can i do that ?)

which allow me to use it in my java application (i need to show the results of my program Matlab in My java application "java FX")

what do you think ?

help me please, and if you want more explanation, i will be here

thank you

Comment: Are you saying you want to run a MATLAB program from Java, and display the results in the Java program?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: @childofsoong Yes exactly

Comment: i heard once that Matlab can generate a file ( result file .mat) and java display it, So why i need to know how to save the result data in a file to display it in java, and i think is the easy way to communicate java with Matlab

Comment: If you want to start MATLAB from Java, then you're going to want to start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774432/starting-a-process-in-java.  You'll just need to figure out how to run MATLAB on command line.  These also might have some insights for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826384/how-can-i-suppress-matlabs-command-window-when-calling-it-from-java?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876135/using-java-to-command-matlab?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [diary](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diary.html) function: it will collect the output to the command window into a text file.